# What must certain internal methods of TDataset do?

Tags: database, delphi

I'm currently subclassing TDataset for my job. However the lack of documentation on the process is making this more difficult than it should be.

I'm currently wondering what InternalInsert and InternalAddRecord should do?

Also if anyone can point me to a good guide that isn't [Custom Dataset](http://www.gexperts.com/articles/customds.asp) or the [Keeping Hold of Your Things series](http://www.carterconsulting.org.uk/) or [Datasets without databases](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20587). That would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tiOPF framework (OR Mapper) has a method to use an objectlist as a dataset. They have all the methods implemented, so it might be worth ckecking out the source (it's all open source).

The source for their TtiCustomDataset (subclassed from TDataset) van be found here: http://tiopf.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tiopf/tiOPF2/Trunk/Options/tiDataset.pas?revision=1544&view=markup

Comment: Thanks, this code is a lot easier to read than the BDE stuff and is almost exactly what I needed :)